# Finding & Removing the top 10 largest numbers and the top 10 smallest numbers of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to ask about an issue regarding an array I have generated an array with 100 integers

```
//Generate 100 numbers
        var arr = [];
        while(arr.length < 100){
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
            if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
        }
        console.log(arr);
```

My issue is Finding and Eliminating the top 10 maximum and Minimum of the array

```
        //Find the Minimum 


        for (let i=0; i != 10; i++){

            arr.splice(Math.min(...arr), 1)

        }
            

        //Find the Maximum

        
        for (let i=0; i != 10; i++){
            

                arr.splice(Math.max(...arr), 1)
            
        
        }
```

and the result is only 90 of the array is eliminated is the maximum & minimum code fighting?

Comment: what is `newArray`

Comment: The first argument to [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is the **index** of the element to remove, not the value of th element to remove.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder would arr.splice(arr.IndexOf(Math.min(...arr), 1) work?

Comment: @brk i was messing around with the code trying to figure what was wrong i reedited it  thank you.

Comment: @RafaelNathanAng - Give it a try!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder so I did try it the array vanished oof but I get what you mean! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the index of the `max` and `min` value from the `arr` and then use `splice`. Also change `i != 10;` to `i<10`

```js
var arr = [];
while (arr.length < 100) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const min = arr.indexOf(Math.min(...arr));
  arr.splice(min, 1)

}
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const max = arr.indexOf(Math.max(...arr));
  arr.splice(max, 1)

};

console.log(arr.length)
```

Comment: Can i ask why not i != 10 but rather i < 10 since i was told before i != 10 was better.?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and then use the splice method to remove the first and last 10 elements.

```
var arr = [];
while (arr.length < 100) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  if (arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}

arr.sort((a, b) => +a - +b);

arr.splice(0, 10);

arr.splice(80, 10);

console.log(arr.length);
```